# Parts of table not capable of resolving connection

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following model:

[image]

With the following connections:

[image]

Feeding a Table visual where (for now) I am adding attributes from the following tables:

```
factLocation

factPo

dimLocation

dimProduct
```

Most of the items are added properly from all the table, but when it comes to adding items from the factPo table, I am running into a problem.

The following columns can be added fine:

```
QuantityOrdered

LineKey

UnitCost

ErightedCost
```

But if I try to add any of the following items:

```
ETADate

LocationKey

ProKey

RequiredDate

SkuCode

SkuStage
```

I get the following error message:

```
Can't display the visual. See details, and the details are:

Can't determine relationships between the fields
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to make the connection between factPo and factLocation by-directional. Better yet, find a way to get rid of factPo.

Comment: The model has ambiguity because there are two paths from dimLocation to factPo (the direct relationship and an indirect relationship via factLocation). Is there any reason to connect factLocation and factPo? Why not get rid of it and connect dimProduct -> factPo instead?